# Tomcat6 MySQL Unknown column in 'field list'"

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat6

I'm working in a RedHat with Tomcat6 and MySQL, and i'll apreciate your help with a problem, i have a servlet connected to my DB , well, I send a sql "String" to my servlet and the servlet executes this code,  i'm printing my sql string, something like this

```
"INSERT INTO xsn_core_helix_streams_stats (timestamp,type,client,publish_time,connects,id_stream,server) VALUES('2013/02/11 16:23:27',null,null,null,'1','4',6);"
```

but i have receiving an Exception

```
 "java.sql.SQLException: Unknown column 'server' in 'field list'"
```

and when i describe my table , i can see the column , and when i copy and paste  in the console , i can see "Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)"
Why?

Comment: Try ``server`` (back-quotes around "server")

Comment: Another thought: try removing the semicolon at the end of the SQL string.

Comment: i tried , but it doesn't works

Answer (score 1):

Despite the responses from @paulsm4 and @ilopezluna, `SERVER` is not a reserved word in MySQL.  Cf. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

I would therefore double-check that your table `xsn_core_helix_streams_stats` actually has a column named `server`.

For instance, try opening the MySQL client, ready the database, and run `SHOW CREATE TABLE LIKE xsn_core_helix_streams_stats`.

I can reproduce the error you report by creating a table *without* a column named `server`, and attempting the INSERT statement in your example.

Comment: when i run CREATE TABLE xsn_core_helix_streams_stats2 like xsn_core_helix_streams_stats;  the output was Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec), and a desc to the new table , it show me all the fields including "server" :(

Answer (score 0):

My workbench mark the word "server", so maybe is a reserved word. Try to change the name of column in your table and query and try again

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, tomcat6 backs my servlet configuration file (Servlet / META-INF / context.xml) and place it in / etc/tomcat6/Catalina/localhost, then the matter is that this file was not correct, greetings and thanks!!